# Tsql date column update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-update

I have a date column that is in **yyyy-mm-dd** I want to convert it to **dd/mm/yyyyy**. The data type for this column is **nvarchar(20)** .I am willing to change the data type. The query i tried is

```
Update table1
set Column1= Convert(nvarchar(10),column1,101).
```

It is executing but is not making any change.

Comment: If you're willing to change the data type, why not just change it to `date` or `datetime`? Then you don't have to worry about formats, and all the date functions will work correctly.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the value twice,

```
Update table1 
set Column1 = CONVERT(nvarchar(10),CONVERT(datetime, REPLACE(column1,'-','.'), 102), 103)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df7ab/1)

Comment: Thank you JW. It worked I just changed the 102 to 101 for the format I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Your data is not **really** a date. It is currently a string, so `Convert` won't have any effect.

You would need to:

`update table1 set Column1 = Convert(nvarchar(10), Convert(datetime, column1), 101)`

but better still, you should consider changing the column data type to `datetime`, then `convert`ing it to the desired format when you `select` data from the table.

Comment: Thank you for your help the query worked but updated the column to feb 02 199.

Comment: change it to `nvarchar(11)` then, then field was slightly too short for the conversion